# Looking for a way to retrieve timezones in which the current time is x

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone, iana

I am looking for a way to obtain a list of timezones in which the current time is a variable (it has to be DST dependant as well).

For example I need to push messages to users for which the local time is 18:45. I can fetch from our database a list of users by timezone. So I plan a scheduled event that would wake up at every 15 minutes, it will need to check in which timezones it is currently 18:45 in order to be able to retrieve the right users.

Our environment is node js.
The *way* I am thinking about is preferably a web service or some utility that does it all for me including the updates from [iana timezones](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) database. But I can handle less convenient ways if there's no such alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple way to do it with `moment-timezone` (I believe it handles things like daylight savings time etc., not 100% sure -- but certainly will do it better than one could do starting from scratch alone.. see their github repo for issues -- its a complex topic):

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var tm = moment();

var toFind = tm.format('h:mm a');

var userZones = ['America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York'];
for (var i=0; i<userZones.length; i++) {
  var fmt = tm.tz(userZones[i]).format('h:mm a');
  if (fmt === toFind) console.log('matched zone: ' + userZones[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, moment timezone implements the data from the IANA time zone DB, so DST is handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks, this was more or less what I did eventually. The annoying part with this was the need to obtain all possible timezones that might be relevant to my users in advance. And I used moment's .isBetween(...) as I needed to  check if the time is in the space of 5 minutes.